# How to text ellipsis overflow in table row with cell percentages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.container{
  background-color: gray;
}

.listing-row{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin 0;
}

.listing-row-inner{
  display: table-row;
  background-color: yellow;
  
}

.tc{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.listing-row-image{
  width: 30%;
}

.listing-row-content{
  width: 70%;
}

.stretch {
    width : 40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.abs{
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top:0px;
  background-color: #0BB7A5;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row container">
  <div class="col-sm-8"> 
    <div class="listing-row">
      <div class="listing-row-inner">
        <div class="tc listing-row-image" >left</div>
        <div class="tc listing-row-content">
          <span class="stretch"> 
           BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
          </span>   
          <span class="abs">AA</span>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

I Need to wrap the text in the right side respecting the left side and the column on the right in gray.
I have tried everything and searched on the internet, nothing seems to work.

I put min-width to the table-cell in the left side but then it takes space on the gray side.

Comment: _This property only affects content that is overflowing a block container element_. Change the `span` to a `div` or add `display:block` to `.stretch`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add display:inline-block in stretch class and set your desire width

```css
.container{
  background-color: gray;
}

.listing-row{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin 0;
}

.listing-row-inner{
  display: table-row;
  background-color: yellow;
  
}

.tc{
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.listing-row-image{
  width: 30%;
}

.listing-row-content{
  width: 70%;
}

.stretch {
    width : 40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}

.abs{
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top:0px;
  background-color: #0BB7A5;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row container">
  <div class="col-sm-8"> 
    <div class="listing-row">
      <div class="listing-row-inner">
        <div class="tc listing-row-image" >left</div>
        <div class="tc listing-row-content">
          <span class="stretch"> 
           BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
          </span>   
          <span class="abs">AA</span>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @juliangonzalez  inline element cannot be sized, you need to reset the display property , so it can be sized and overflow comes avalaible ;)

Comment: you can just add float in span and change the value of witdh to percentage

Comment: yep, it is all about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

Comment: Thank you guys. this actually answer the question. However what I need is to set a responsive width with percentages.I was too tired when asked. Please help me out using width: 70% without screwing the whole screen.

I tried floating but doesnt work here's a screenshot of expected vs obtained. 
Small screen http://screenshot.co/#!/d46f74ebd8
Big screen http://screenshot.co/#!/da6715a218
What I get: http://screenshot.co/#!/b760b8cb62

float: left;
    width : 70%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;

Comment: I'd like to become a pro in CSS but right now I dont understand too much the docs and need to get this done :(

Comment: @AntonioCanillas can you please help me with this? You can post it as a new answer I will upvote :)